# Can I give anonymous object a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
hello({
  name: "Michael"
} as x) // <-- Except missing id here, but it doesn't

type x = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

function hello(x: any) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BYUwNmD2AUDeBQACRA7AhgWxALkQIgFkBLAY2DXD3gF9E0BnRADwEp54AXATwAcRnEAXkQJkRACa56HAE5EUAcySpMORNLmKa7AGYBXFCQ5FIKRKAgwmuFiOUlT9SGBAA6KAuittQA)

This code throws no error beside I'm saying `as x`. This is a type assertion so it won't give me an error. However I want to check for the type here. How can I do this? I'm not able to modify the `hello` function in my code.

Comment: Create a wrapper function which calls hello and add types in that.

Comment: If `hello` function takes an argument of type `any`, you don't need to cast the object.

Comment: In addition to @Vishwanath's comment: Something like `function typeCheck<T>(obj: T) { return obj; }` and `hello(typeCheck<x>({name: "Michael"}))`. An example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BYUwNmD2AUDeBQACRA7AhgWxALkQIgFkBLAY2DXD3gF9E0BnRADwEp54AXATwAcRnEAXkQJkRACa56HAE5EUAcySpMORNLmKa7AGYBXFCQ5FIKRNz4BhUCQDWAHgAqAPmiQARgCtcjliMQyIBx6MmYengDciNTsoBAwFiDWIHb2TK6w6Fi4hKTklNQsbPD6hsamiHFQ0Ey4aChcfqKIJKb0kGAgAHRQCjVsMUA

Comment: @Raphaël I want to check for the type because when the type of `x` changes I want to get notified where I have to do modifications.

Comment: @Vishwanath This is an idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a generic type checker function:

```
function typeCheck<T>(obj: T) { return obj; }

hello(typeCheck<x>({
  name: "Michael"
}));

type x = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

function hello(x: any) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAngBwKYGEAWGIDWAPACoB8AFHAEYBWAXIiQJSIDeiAThlCJ0jVoBuRAF8AUOLwAbaXAqpMufMQAelNuMSIwAQwC2GRgCIAsjAg5dGacfGjmzIZMUZEqxAF52WxDAAmjADOUJwwYADmvnqGwaHhURLioJCwCIgychSqjLpgKKya2hAIQXDSGAB0chHZzPZAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper function where you can put your type and ask developers to use your function instead of hello directly.

```
hello({
  name: "Michael"
} as x) // <-- Except missing id here, but it doesn't

type x = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

function hello(x: any) {
  console.log(x)
}


type x = {
  id: string
  name: string
}

function myHello(x: x) {
  return hello(x)
}

myHello({
  name: "Michael"
}) // Will show error
```